# How should I modify my dataset and D3.JS code to add a group name?

Tags: d3.js

Here is my dataset

```
var dataset = [{ x: 0, y: 100  }, { x: 1, y: 833  }, { x: 2, y: 1312 },
              { x: 3, y: 1222 }, { x: 4, y: 1611 },
              { x: 0, y: 200  }, { x: 1, y: 933  }, { x: 2, y: 1412 },
              { x: 3, y: 1322 }, { x: 4, y: 1711 },]
```

I'm not sure where to specify the name of each dataset, How should this be modified to allow for a Group Name to be passed and what changes should be made in my D3.JS code ?

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qvrL3ey5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using http://jsfiddle.net/2N2rt/15/ I was able to resolve this issue.

Example

```
var data = [
{name: 'John', values: [0,1,3,9, 8, 7]},
{name: 'Harry', values: [0, -100, 7, 1, 1, 111]},
{name: 'Steve', values: [3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 107]},
{name: 'Adam', values: [4, 77, 2, 13, 11, 130]}
];
```